# QT QFileDialog doesn't list all available files in target directory

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

When calling the static function QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames() from a dialog in my application, I get only one file extension defined by the file filters (rather than both), and only a single file from the target directory (rather all the files available).

Here is getOpenFileNames() being called from from main():

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QString>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  QStringList filenames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(
            NULL,
            "Select data file",
            "/home/gss/Data/",
            "Data Files (*.raw *.RAW)" );
}
```

Browsing to the desired directory with the dialog results in all the .raw and .RAW files being shown.

QT Creator 5.0.2
CentOS 8

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Note that your filter specifies `*RAW` rather than `*.RAW` -- is that deliberate?  Have you tried both native and non-native dialogs?

Comment: Modified the posting with minimal code to get reproducible results. The *RAW was a typo and has been corrected.

Comment: Modified the posting with a minimal call from main(). @G.M.: The *RAW was a typo and has been corrected. I tested both native and non-native with an instantiated QFileDialog--there is no change in outcome.

Answer (score 0):

[doc.qt.io](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileNames)

says:

```
QStringList files = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(
                        this,
                        "Select one or more files to open",
                        "/home",
                        "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)");
```

please, try

```
QStringList filenames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(
          this,
          "Select data file",
          "/home/gss/Data",
          "Data Files (*.raw *.RAW)" );
```

Comment: The only difference between your getOpenFileNames( ) call and mine is the the trailing slash in the directory argument. There is no change in the results.